# Thymeleaf: Replace div with other pages on controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new to thymeleaf.

CustomerController.java

```
  @RequestMapping(value = {"dashboard", ""}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexDashboard() {
        return "dashboard::dashboard_index";
    }
  @RequestMapping(value = {"dashboard/edit", ""}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editDashboard() {
        return "dashboard::dashboard_edit";
    }
```

dashboard.html

```
It is main page
<div id="content"></div>
```

dashboard_index.html

```
<div>dashboard_index</div>
```

dashboard_edit.html

```
<div>dashboard_edit</div>
```

I want replace content div with other pages on controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into template fragments from the sounds of it:

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#rendering-template-fragments

You can either use javascript to call a controller specific to the fragment, and then load it into your page.

OR

Load it directly using th:include or th:replace while passing the relevant values in via the same controller method.

Comment: thanks for reply. I found any solution about this. But i think its not simple.


dashboard.html
<div id="content" th:fragment="setFragment(content_fragment)></div>

and i return this view from any controller

return "dashboard::setFragment(content_fragment='dealer/create_project_form')";

Comment: If you read the section in that link you will see the different ways you can do this. This can be as simple as doing a th:include or as complex as calling fragments as exposed beans.

Comment: @Gnosis00 Your solution worked for me to. But can you tell me how to load CSS now? What is blocking it?