# Can't load CSS in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**I use this solutions for including one thymeleaf in another. It is solved my problems, but now css file don't load at all**

[Thymeleaf: Replace div with other pages on controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126791/thymeleaf-replace-div-with-other-pages-on-controllers)

Here is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/allUsers")
    public String userList(Model theModel) {
        List<User> theUsers = userService.findAll();
        theModel.addAttribute("users", theUsers);
        return "dashboard :: setFragment(content_fragment='/admin/allUsers')";
    }
```

and part of the html where is link to css file

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
        
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var includes = $('[data-include]');
                $.each(includes, function () {
                    var file = '/admin' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';
                    $(this).load(file);
                });
            });
        </script> 
        <title>Dashboard</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div th:insert="fragments/header :: header"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="content" th:fragment="setFragment(content_fragment)">
                <div th:insert="fragments/dashboard :: aside" class="col-md-2 px-3"></div>
                <div th:insert="fragments/users :: users" class="col-md-10 py-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this language however you may have to load your css as follows:

```
<link th:href="@{"/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Using the example from: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-css-js